# Can we use NLP to understand/parse/compile programming code?

Tags: natural-language-processing, machine-translation

I wonder if we can use Natural Language Processing (NLP) to process programming code:
Given a piece of code, can we

1. **Translate** it to human language to *understand* what it does? The input could be a function definition（normally lack of documentation) in Python and the output could be the documentation for that function.
2. **Compile** or translate it to another programming language? Compile Python code to C or machine code, or translate C code to Python code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and that is the ambition of the [Decoder](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project (H2020 funded in Europe). Analyzing with NLP techniques the comments in e.g. C or C++ source code (of open source projects, and perhaps their [`git`](https://git-scm.com/) logs).

I even happen to be on the photo.

My dream is to try similar things, in a few years, in [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/). You could join that project, BTW.

Comment: I just discovered that we are neighbors :)